# How to filter on results of a comprehension?

Tags: python

Say I have an array of Xs, and need to put them through a filter, then transform each item in the result into an array of Ys

```
[for (x of Xs) if (condition(x)) transform(x)]
```

But then I have another filter that depends on the results of the first filter, e.g. only return items in the filtered array that are within 2 standard deviations

What do I do?

Comment: I guess your question is not quite clear. Could you explain with different words?

Comment: Do you mean `[transform(x) for x in Xs if condition(x)]`?

Comment: Try writing your algorithm with traditional loops first. Seeing a working algorithm can be very helpful in refactoring it (if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of then the way to do this is to nest several comprehensions or generator expressions. You may be able to do the whole thing in one complicated expression, but it can be clearer if you split them up.

For instance, if you want to transform the values of a list with a `transform` function, and want to filter out some of the values (based on the transformed result, not the original input), you could use:

```
result = [x for x in (transform(y) for y in some_iterable) if condition(x)]
```

or

```
transform_gen = (transform(y) for y in some_iterable)
filtered_list = [x for x in transform_gen if condition(x)]
```

You can of course add as many extra layers of nesting as you need.